# Disable and re-enable a function, Mute and Unmute

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Hi I am trying to disable a function with a click of a button and then enable it again once another button is clicked I have tried unbind but I am getting no where
any suggestions to how I can go about this?

Code:

```
<a href="#" class="MuteOn">Mute</a>
<a href="#" class="MuteOff">Unmute</a>

$('.MuteOn').on('click tap touch', function() {
//Disable soundListen function
 });

$('.MuteOff').on('click tap touch', function() {
//Enable soundListen function
 });
```

//

```
setInterval(function soundListen() {
    if ($("body").hasClass("fp-viewing-1")) {
        audio1.play();

    } else {
        audio1.pause();
        audio1.currentTime = 0;
    }

    if ($("body").hasClass("fp-viewing-2")) {
        audio2.play();
    } else {
        audio2.pause();
        audio2.currentTime = 0;
    }

    if ($("body").hasClass("fp-viewing-3")) {
        audio3.play();
    } else {
        audio3.pause();
        audio3.currentTime = 0;
    }
}, 100);
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: have you tried .off() function?

Comment: Should mute button just mute sound or stop playback. You just can set audio to loop and stop/set volum to 0 when mute pressed. Or you can put some bool value,which can be set by mute/unmute, and call return at begin of your function if it is true.

Comment: No I've  not tried .on() and .off() I shell try that now @maximelian1986 the mute button should stop the soundListen function either mute sound or pause it in turn no sounds will play and then when the unmute button is pressed it should enable the soundListen function again and then it will play the according audio depending on the body class

Comment: Cant seem to get .on() or .off() to work

Comment: Is it background music for web site, or some music for game? I mean do you need that soundListen function at all. You can start loop music playback on start/load and stop/mute on button press. Then you change music with class name at body, so you set that class from somewhere. Isn't it easier to change audio clip at the same moment? So if you describe more about your logic and about music playback flow, I can suggest you more optimal option.

Comment: it is music that plays on certain slides I don't need the function soundListen I just need the setInterval and the function inside of that the mute button is on the 1st slide if i click it and pause/mute all the music and then go onto the 2nd slide the music on the 2nd slide etc will play because the body changes and the setInterval is checking it constantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I understood it like this:
-On first page user can click mute/unmute button and that should be saved during navigation through all other pages/slides.

Then here is a code:

```
<!doctype>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="mute">Mute</button>
        <button id="unmute">Unmute</button>
        <button id="reloadPage">Reload Page</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            //get variable from local variables or set to false(you can change it to TRUE if you like to mute on page load) by default
            var isMuted = localStorage.getItem("IsMuted")||false;

            //mute button onclick method
            $(document).on('click','#mute',function(e){
                isMuted = true;
                //save to local variables
                localStorage.setItem("IsMuted", isMuted);
            }); 

            //unmute button onclick method
            $(document).on('click','#unmute',function(e){
                isMuted = false;
                //save to local variables
                localStorage.setItem("IsMuted", isMuted);
            }); 

            //reload page. also you can use F5 or Ctrl+F5
            $(document).on('click','#reloadPage',function(e){
                location.reload();
            });

            $(document).ready(function(){
                alert("IsMuted = "+isMuted);

                //you can encapsulate this into separate function and bind to show-next-slide button                
                if(isMuted)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    //get clip id by class name or another suitable method
                    PlayMyCoolMusic(clipId);
                }
            });



            function PlayMyCoolMusic(clipId)
            {
                //your audio player logic here

            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

With this you can save you mute/unmute status even if page has been reloaded.